# Disassembling an Asus S56CB to expose its msata disk

Tags: laptop, disassembly

I bought an msata SSD disk to replace the U100 that comes with this laptop.

Now I can't figure out how to disassemble and install it.

Usually Google is very generous with hints, but not this time.

After removing all the bottom screws (I'm not sure if there is one hidden under a squared rubber pad), I don't know how to proceed to expose the motherboard.

Comment: There is no need for bad language

Comment: @DaveRook you're right: I should pay more attention (swear words are not as apparent to non native speakers). Is there something else wong with the question? Even after your edit, it has one downvote I don't understand.

Comment: No worries. I did the downvote due to the swearing and just forgot to take it off, have now removed it. You didn't explain what is puzzling you. I mean, did you try to unscrew it (are there even screws), or did you take it apart and something else stop you? A question of "how do I do everything" is too broad typically for this website. If you are not confident / comfortable about this update, I would suggest you take it to a shop to have them do it but *usually* this change does effect your warranty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it on the Asus site ("Asus S56CB Ultrabook User Manual"), or looking for "User Manual" on several documentation sites. The disk replacement instructions are at [page 64](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/S56CB/Manual/338789?page=64).

There are two screws on the bottom front panel, and once removed, the hard disk is exposed. It is locked with four other screws and can be lifted by gently pulling on its front tab.

The procedure for mSATA should be [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/698655-asus-s56ca-wh31-15-6-ultrabook-teardown-integrated-ssd-hack-os-install-hack.html#post8970401) (with pictures), with some caveats:

> There is only one screw holding the 24GB mSATA SSD to the motherboard.
> Once removed, set the screw aside and the mSATA SSD will pop up, just
> like a stick of ram.
>
> Test fitting the 128GB Crucial mSATA SSD, a problem arose. The
> standoff used to secure the 24GB integrated SSD is getting in the way!
> The standoff will need to be removed.

**The bad news:**

> ** WARNING ** Removing the standoff that secures the OEM 24GB mSATA SSD to the PCB will instantly void the warranty. It won't damage the
> computer, as long as you are careful, but you can consider your
> warranty gone once you do this. To remove the standoff, I used a pair
> of bent nose pliers to firmly grasp the aluminum standoff, taking
> GREAT CARE not to scrape, contact, or otherwise disturb any part of
> the PCB or motherboard circuitry; once the standoff is grasped, twist
> clockwise or counterclockwise (again, CAREFULLY), and it should come
> off, relatively easily. You don't need herculean strength to twist it
> off, just firmness, and finesse.

**The good news:**

The guy apparently has now a Crucial 128GB instead of the original mSATA accelerator.

Comment: This will expose the 2.5 sata disk, but not the msata connector. The disk I want to replace is connected to the latter.

Comment: (Updated answer)

Comment: Thanks! Tomorrow I'll buy a couple of bent nose pliers. I couldn't remove the standoff with my straight ones.

Answer (score 0):

The S46 models look very similar to the S56 series.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5E7viTdMl4) shows an already disassembled S46CM. Using a guitar pick to separate the two components of the shell [as showed here on a x301](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNszlNlEcW0) should work.

The warranty will much likely be voided by the disk replacement.